# Blog redirection to directory in Heroku app is not working for blog post urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku

I followed [this tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/wordpress-inside-a-ruby-on-rails-app-c324fbf39ad8) in order to redirect my blog hosted on a subdomain (blog.botletter.com) to a directory of my Heroku rails app (https://www.botletter.com/blog/).

The redirection works for the main page of the blog (/blog/) but does not for the articles URLs.

I guess it's a problem of configuration within the Rails app but I can't find the mistake. Here is the log in Heroku:

> at=info method=GET path="/blog/invite-team-members/"
>   host=www.botletter.com request_id=23b81c9a-e20b-4261-aea4-87adfb781554
>   fwd="195.154.32.17" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=412ms status=500
>   bytes=725 protocol=https

Here is my config.ru file (I don't use username and passwork like in the tutorial as the blog is not using any access restriction):

```
require_relative 'config/environment'

use Rack::ReverseProxy do
  reverse_proxy /^\/blog(\/.*)$/, 'https://blog.botletter.com$1', :timeout => 500, :preserve_host => true
end

run Rails.application
```

My routes:

```
get '/blog' => redirect("https://www.botletter.com/blog/")
get '(*path)', to: 'application#blog', constraints: { subdomain: 'blog' }
```

My "blog" action in the application controller:

```
def blog
    redirect_to "https://www.botletter.com/blog#{request.fullpath.gsub('/blog','')}", :status => :moved_permanently
  end
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> at=info method=GET path="/blog/invite-team-members/" host=www.botletter.com

I see subdomain is `www`

> get '(*path)', to: 'application#blog', constraints: { subdomain:
>   'blog' }

You're restring subdomain to be `blog`, so you need add the subdomain to your blog's path.